# How to find an element which is between a pair in the set of pairs?

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, stl

```
set<pair<int,int> >s;
pair<int,int>a0 = make_pair(1,10); // pair is kind of range of integer
air<int,int>a1 = make_pair(11,50);
s.insert(a0);
s.insert(a1);
```

Now I need a function  which returns true when I search any integer which lies between range of any pair in the set.

Comment: `for (auto& p : s) { if (p.first <= x && p.second >= x) return true; if (p.first > x) break; } return false;` The fact that you have them in a set doesn't really help you much (except that you can stop early once the first component becomes too large).

Comment: What have you tried? What do you have so far?

Comment: Can i accomplish this  task better than this using any other data structure.

Comment: @KamleshKumar Is the first of the pair always <= the second of the pair?  What if the pair contains `(50,11)`?

Comment: @KamleshKumar You ask: `Can i accomplish this task better than this using any other data structure`. To answer that you need to define what `better` means. Is it better performance? Less memory usage? Less code? More maintainable code? Also it is important how your program will use the data. Many inserts/deletes? Many look ups?

Comment: first one is always lesser than second one in every pair?

Comment: better in sense of time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now I need a function which returns true when I search any integer which lies between range of any pair in the set.

It seems a work for `std::any_of()`

```
#include <set>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

bool anyRange (std::set<std::pair<int, int>> const & s, int v)
 { return std::any_of(s.cbegin(), s.cend(),
                      [&](std::pair<int, int> const & p)
                       { return (p.first <= v) && (v <= p.second); }); }

int main()
 {
   std::set<std::pair<int, int>> s { {1, 10}, {11, 50} };

   std::cout << anyRange(s, -5) << std::endl; // print 0
   std::cout << anyRange(s, 5)  << std::endl; // print 1
   std::cout << anyRange(s, 25) << std::endl; // print 1
   std::cout << anyRange(s, 75) << std::endl; // print 0
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Iterate over the set and check if the integer is in each pair inside the set

```
bool bet(set<pair<int,int> > s, int integer) 
{
    for (auto it : s)
    {
        if (it.first <= integer && it.second >= integer) 
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: This will probably work but it doesn't use the fact that the container is a `set` (i.e. elements are sorted). The code would be the same for a `vector`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want fast search (i.e. better than linear) then you should use [interval tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree). std::set is not suitable for this problem